# layout setMargins doesn't work in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, margins

I have one static layout and I set margin in programmatic dynamic. Margin  works fine but just in portrait view only. This is xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/menubackground"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="ActiveMenu"
            android:text="@string/home"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_browse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/menubackground"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_browse"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="ActiveMenu"
            android:text="@string/browse"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/menubackground"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/btn_account"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="ActiveMenu"
            android:text="@string/account"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_mybag"
        android:background="@drawable/menubackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/btn_mybag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="ActiveMenu"
            android:text="@string/my_bag"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_no_Of_items"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_mybag"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/red_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="15.0dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/menubackground"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/btn_more"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="ActiveMenu"
            android:text="@string/more"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I wrote following code for margin

```
    Button btn_home,    btn_browse, btn_account,    btn_mybag,  btn_more;
    RelativeLayout  rl_home,    rl_browse,  rl_account, rl_mybag,   rl_more;
    LinearLayout LinearLayout1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.browse);


        btn_home=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_home);
        btn_browse=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_browse);
        btn_account=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_account);
        btn_mybag=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mybag);
        btn_more=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_more);

        rl_home=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_home);
        rl_browse=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_browse);
        rl_account=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_account);
        rl_mybag=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_mybag);
        rl_more=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_more);
        LinearLayout1=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    }

    public void ActiveMenu(View v) {


        if (R.id.btn_home == v.getId()) {
            rl_home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.current_menu);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            rl_home.setLayoutParams(params);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params1.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 0);

            rl_browse.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_browse.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_account.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_account.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_mybag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_mybag.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_more.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_more.setLayoutParams(params1);

        }

        if (R.id.btn_browse== v.getId()) {
            rl_browse.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.current_menu);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            rl_browse.setLayoutParams(params);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params1.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 0);

            rl_home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_home.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_account.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_account.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_mybag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_mybag.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_more.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_more.setLayoutParams(params1);

        }

        if (R.id.btn_account == v.getId()) {

            rl_account.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.current_menu);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            rl_account.setLayoutParams(params);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params1.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 0);

            rl_browse.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_browse.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_home.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_mybag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_mybag.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_more.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_more.setLayoutParams(params1);
        }

        if (R.id.btn_mybag == v.getId()) {
            rl_mybag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.current_menu);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            rl_mybag.setLayoutParams(params);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params1.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 0);

            rl_browse.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_browse.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_account.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_account.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_home.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_more.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_more.setLayoutParams(params1);
        }

        if (R.id.btn_more== v.getId()) {
            rl_more.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.current_menu);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            rl_more.setLayoutParams(params);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params1.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 0);


            rl_browse.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_browse.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_account.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_account.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_home.setLayoutParams(params1);
            rl_mybag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
            rl_mybag.setLayoutParams(params1);
        }

    }
```

Is any mistake I made??
Portrate view 
[image]

landscape view  [image]

after changing current item in landscape view 
[image]

Comment: in landscape mode margin works fine but it can't fit to screen..when layout load fist time than it was fit to screen but after fired click event it can't stay as fit to screen..

Comment: problem is in 3rd image...after click in any item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.  In my old posted code I wrote this code

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params1.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 0);
```

And I have change below code.. this  solved my problem.

```
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) rl_home
                .getLayoutParams();
params1.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 0);
rl_home.setLayoutParams(params1);
```